# How to customize the default help text for the command line python-fire by google?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, command-line-tool, python-fire

I am trying to make a small command line tool using [python-fire module by google](https://github.com/google/python-fire).
My filename is my_tools.py.
Inside my_tools.py I have code

```
class MainFunction():
   def __init__(self):
      self.config = WrapperConfig()
   def hey_world(self):
      print("hey world")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   fire.Fire(MainFunction)
```

When I run the command python my_tools.py in the terminal I get the Output as:

```
NAME                                                                                                                        
  my_tools.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
SYNOPSIS                                                                                                                    
  my_tools.py GROUP | COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
GROUPS                                                                                                                      
  GROUP is one of the following:                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  config                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
COMMANDS                                                                                                                    
  COMMAND is one of the following:                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  hey_world
```

[View Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6E7Q.png)

Is there any way where I can customize this default help text?

Answer (score 0):

You can add docstring to the class and function.

```py
class MainFunction():
   """description of MainFunction"""
   def __init__(self):
      self.config = WrapperConfig()
   def hey_world(self):
   """description of hey_world"""
      print("hey world")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   fire.Fire(MainFunction)
```

Comment: It seems that the help message doesn't document the entire docstring if the docstring has more than one line of text. How does one mitigate that?